# How to add time with Liquid templates in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: .net, liquid, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I'm trying to add a specific duration to a particular datetime field in my JSON to JSON Transform input Content, using methods as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39730626/11928194). However, [logic apps use dotliquid internally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#create-liquid-template-or-map-for-your-integration-account), [the default config](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid.Website/Views/Docs/Formatting.cshtml#L37) of which uses [.NET date format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [Ruby's](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/).

I could find no available .NET date format alternative for Ruby's %s (returns the number of seconds since the Unix epoch) which is essential to [the operation](https://www.huratips.com/tech-tips/how-to-add-days-to-date-in-shopify-liquid.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Example to add 6 hours and 30 minutes from now and format :

```
{
  "outputKey" : {{ "now" | Date: "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss" | Append: "-06:30" | Date: "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[formatDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime)" method in logic app to customize the format of your date and then put it in Liquid.

Comment: I do not want to customize the format. I want to add a certain timespan to it. As an example, if I receive the json `{"a":"2020-01-27T07:36:31Z"}`, I want to transform it to add, say 6 hours, to the property a and create new json as `{"b":"2020-01-27T13:36:31Z"}`

Comment: Hi @KaustubhBadrike, I think it may be difficult for us to do this operation in liquid. But as a workaround, could you please try to do this with initialize a variable and set the value with "addHours('your datetime in json', 6)". And then add this variable to your json.